# Convert a string into an OWLAxiom object

Tags: java, string, ontology, owl-api

Is it possible to convert a string into an OWLAxiom object using OWLAPI?

For example, if I have this code below:

```
String axiom_str = axiom.toString();
String newAxiom_str = axiom_str.replaceAll(oldClass.getIRI().toString(), newClass.getIRI().toString());
```

Is it possible to create an OWLAxiom object bases on the newAxiom_str? What I want to achieve is to convert the newAxiom_str into an OWLAxiom object. Is there any way so?

Thank you in advance

I am obviously using OWLAPI. I tried using OWLObjectVisitorEx but I didn't have a efficient result...

Comment: To change an IRI, use OWLEntityRenamer. It's designed to work with ontologies and produces change objects, but they contain old and new axioms, so you can probably get what you need that way

Comment: @Ignazio hello! Thank you for the advice. However I don’t want to keep the old axiom with the old IRI. I just want the new axiom with the new IRI. Is that possible? P.S. I have tried using OWLObjectVisitor to do the replacing, and nothing achieved yet. Should I insist using the OWLObjectVisitor though?

Comment: If you want to replace an IRI on all axioms in an ontology, then OWLEntityRenamer will do just that. If you want to refactor just one axiom, then a visitor is one way to do it. OWLObjectDuplicator and OWLEntityRenamer do that, under the cover. You can check their implementation for inspiration, or you can add the code you've written and explain your needs in the question.